# How to forward a port to multiple internal ips

Tags: centos, iptables, openvpn, port-forwarding

I have a Centos 6 64 bit server with OpenVPN installed.

I'm using this iptables rule to forward a port for an OpenVPN user:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport PORT -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.1.X:PORT
```

This works perfect but if I forward the same port for another user. The port will not work for both. How can I forward the same port to 2 different users?

I know I can put the user on a different subnet with a different external IP and forward the traffic on a port on that IP to the client and have the same port open for 2 users like that but that's not what I want to do. I want the users to be on the same subnet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a match on the destination IP using `-d IP`.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -d 9.8.7.X --dport PORT -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.1.X:PORT
```

Considering that 9.8.7.X is your external IP getting the traffic and 10.8.1.X is your internal IP that needs redirecting to.

Comment: Could you give an example? I already use this: "--to-destination 10.8.1.X:PORT" in my iptables rule.

Comment: There we go. I hope it helps. Also, you should read more about IPTABLES :)